# UIImagePickerController crashes app and sometimes restarts the device - memory warning issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

We have customized the camera view and the move&scale options. after taking picture the original image will be opened up in the new view controller which has customized move&scale. It works fine but the app crashes and sometimes os restarts if we are open the camera more than around 7 times continuously. we checked the profile instruments there is no memory leaks its getting released after picture is taken

app throws memory warning continuously after around 7 time continues use of camera

we are using ARC.

Any idea?

Comment: Check your code. Use Instruments.

Comment: are you storing picture taken by came in some iVar? Maybe ur image is not getting released after new image is set.

Comment: @H2CO3 i used instruments, memeory increases 0.3MB when open camera/library and getting relases when closes.

Comment: @iVishal yes, storing into `UIImage`. its stored in single ton class. however it woulb be relased when we assign another image in it?

Comment: application gets crashed as soon as you open the camera or after clicking photo?

Comment: @iVishal after the camera button is clicked! and when images picked from library

Comment: Please post the exact crash message you see in the console and the stack of the crash.

Comment: How you open camera in App? post some code or post crash message?

Comment: i was using the raw camera picture so it occupies so much memory. now its fixed. i just resized the raw camera image. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the answer.there was a problem in image i used for cropping.

See the below links.

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/
http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/tag/uiimagepickercontroller/